# play framework 1.2.4 multiple footer in mutiple PDF page

Tags: pdf, footer, playframework-1.x

I need to render multiple types of footer and header in different PDF pages. How can I do that?
I could only do with single kind of footer in all the PDF pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MultiPDFDocuments documents = new MultiPDFDocuments();
PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
document.template = "@template1";
Options options = new Options();
options.pageSize = IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4L;
document.options = options;
documents.add(document);
document = new PDFDocument();
document.template = "@template2";
options = new Options();
options.pageSize = IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4L;
document.options = options;
documents.add(document);
File file = new File("C:/Users/PDF.pdf");
PDF.writePDF(file,documents);
```